# How to align part of an equation to the right?

Tags: equations, align

I want write to the right of an equation to put what Im doing, how can I do that? I put an image as reference

[image: the words at the right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item $A=B$\hfill C
 \item $D=E$\hfill FG
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]